# installing FMI library and error found- insouce build?

Tags: c, cmake

I am following FMIL build guide and running following commands:

```
mkdir build-fmil; cd build-fmil
cmake -DFMILIB_INSTALL_PREFIX=<prefix> -G "Visual Studio 10" <path to FMIL source>
cmake --build . --config MinSizeRel --target install
```

So I build an empty directory, and set a source, but it keep saying error below.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (message):
  In-source build is not supported.  Please, use an empty directory for
  building the project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I Tried this on VS code terminal.

Comment: What project are you building? Google finds nothing for FMIL.

Comment: If you firstly have attempted to build the project in-source, then following attempts to build it out-of-source will fail unless you remove file `CMakeCache.txt` (not a `CMakeLists.txt`!!) from the source directory.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I use python, and I'd like to export python prediction model to my simulation tool, which requires PyFMI package. It requires libray build preminary, so I try to install that throu VS code..